# Find array with the maximum sum of elements

Tags: python

I have a problem with a task:
"In a given array of integers  of any size  ×   find an array of given size  × ,  < such that the sum of elements in the array  will be the largest possible."
I wanted to create for loop that will check every possible  ×  array and its sum but I failed at cutting a list of lists to a given size. So how can I cut   array of  ×  that it is  × ?
I'm using only build-in functions.

Comment: I think the first problem is making that statement clear without the recursive grammar. It is not a sin to use more than one sentence

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the entries in the two arrays? I'm guessing the second array can be thought of as a square "superimposed" on the first, but you don't make it clear in the question.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. The second array (n×n) is superimposed on the first (m×m).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, use iloc in pandas. See below for an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))

# blocks of size m=2 in a dataframe of size 4
m = 2
n = 4

# prints an mxm block of df and its corresponding sum
for i in range(0, n-m+1):
    for j in range(0, n-m+1):
        tmp_df = df.iloc[i:i+m, j:j+m]
        print(tmp_df)
        print('sum:', tmp_df.values.sum(), '\n')
```

Edit: Just saw your stipulation of only built-in functions. If pandas doesn't fit that bill, what is the form of your data?

Second shot below using list comprehensions instead of pandas.

```
array = [list(range(x, x+4)) for x in range(0,13, 4)]

def slice_array(array, m, start_row, start_col): 
    tmp = [[x for x in row[start_col:start_col+m]] \
           for row in array[start_row:start_row+m]]
    return tmp

 >>> slice_array(array, m=2, start_row=0, start_col=0)
 [[0, 1], [4, 5]]

 >>> slice_array(array, m=2, start_row=0, start_col=1)
 [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: It is array with numers. I was looking for a method like in one dimensional lists, when you cut out only the part you need using for example N = [1:3]. I tried to use it in two dimensions but it did not work.

Comment: Is it a list of lists (e.g., array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])? And you'd like the blocks to be [[1,2], [4,5]], [[2,3], [5,6]], etc.?